# Cannot find the video on the file path returned by stopRecordVideo() function of camera preview plugin of ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am facing issue in finding the recorded video file on the file path returned when I called `stopRecordVideo()` of camera preview plugin in ionic.

The function I used: 
**To start recording**

```
startRecording(){
 options = {
   cameraDirection: this.cameraPreview.CAMERA_DIRECTION.BACK,
   width: (window.screen.width / 2),
   height: (window.screen.height / 2),
   quality: 60,
   withFlash: false,
   storeToFile: true,
 }
 this.cameraPreview.startRecordVideo(options);
}
```

**To stop recording**

```
this.cameraPreview.stopRecordVideo().then((filePath) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(filePath));
            //filePath = "/data/user/0/com.xyz.abc/cache/fileName.mp4
    });
```

I am not getting this file at the location.
I am using this plugin: https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview
Please help me to get the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accessed the video file by the following method:

```
import { File,FileEntry } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

constructor(
    private file: File,
   ) { }
 

this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl("file:///data/user/0/com.xyz.abc/cache/fileName.mp4")
    .then(entry => {
      (<FileEntry>entry).file(file => {


        alert(JSON.stringify(file));
      }
      );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert('Error while reading file.' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```